# 1440p 144hz flat screen gaming monitor recommendation

Tags: monitors

I want to build a gaming system to play FPS, Racing and VR games at 1440p 144hz. I need a 27" or 28" monitor recommendation that is a flat-screen, but no bigger as the monitors would stick off of the desk and be partially (by an inch or two) in the walkway.

That display have a DisplayPort, HDMI port, a VESA mount and 1MS response time.

The included stand must be removable, as I am going to mount the monitor to a VESA mount, next to a Samsung 28" 4k 60hz monitor.

If it has a USB passthrough or RGB, It'd be a bonus but not required. I don't care if it has AMD FreeSync or Nvidia G-Sync in it, because I am using a FreeSync monitor currently with an Nvidia GTX 1050 and I have no issues with it.

The budget for the monitor is around $300 USD but feel free to push the budget up to $400, due to the inflated prices of COVID-19 and I would buy the monitor around Black Friday.

I like the brands, [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/gaming/), [Dell/Alienware](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/alienware-monitors/ar/alienware_monitors), [MSI](https://us.msi.com/Monitors), [BenQ](https://www.benqdirect.com/monitors/gaming.html), [AOC](https://us.aoc.com/en/gaming), [ASUS/ROG](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/Monitors-Products/), [Acer/Predator](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/predator-models/monitors), [LG](https://www.lg.com/us/gaming-monitors), and [Gigabyte/AORUS](https://www.gigabyte.com/Monitor). I like those brands of monitors, but you don't have to stick within these brands if you give me a good argument about why it is a good monitor for what I need.

Comment: I would accept a 27" or 28", just no bigger because the monitors would stick off of the desk at that point

Answer (score 1):

[Acer XF270HU Cbmiiprx](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.HX0AA.C03) gaming monitor is [$330 shipped today at Amazon/BuyBurg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YGY3RMQ)

[Acer KG271U is $250 today](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/UM.HX1AA.011) or [$300 FOB Destination at Compsource](https://www.compsource.com/buy/UMHX1AA011/Acer-10/?src=F).

[Acer VG270U](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/models/monitors/vg0) is [$360 shipped today from Newegg](https://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9B-24-011-243).

[ASUS MG278Q](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/MG278Q/specifications/) is [$400 shipped at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014X4U076).

[Asus VG27BQ](https://www.asus.com/Monitors/TUF-Gaming-VG27BQ/specifications/) is [$400 w/ shipping from B&H Photo](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1506379-REG/asus_27_tuf_vg27bq_extreme.html/?ap=y&ap=y&smp=y&smp=y&lsft=BI%3A514&gclid=CjwKCAjw95D0BRBFEiwAcO1KDMkTkaWDCWK074wCa5UiFX5t4UddF2R1WY2U5ctUbbwle_lfvvx9JxoCBYcQAvD_BwE).

[.](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS804US804&tbm=shop&sxsrf=ALeKk02aS6vT9-lVAj7ivUm4nGDC5S5B_Q:1585765264095&q=28%22%20flat%20display%20DP%20HDMI%20VESA%20QHD%201ms%20144Hz%20-curved&tbs=vw:l,mr:1,price:1,ppr_min:250,ppr_max:400,pdtr0:716339%7C716340!716341!716361!716343!716369!716346,pdtr1:721168%7C721182!721169,pdtr2:718959%7C721179,pdtr3:1160904%7C68.58000183105469%2480.01000213623047,cat:305,pdtr4:960753%7C960754&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4q43668foAhW6GTQIHRkIDR8QsysIrAgoAA&biw=1536&bih=722)

Comment: Is there any other monitors that you'd recommend by Dell/Alienware, Samsung or LG?

Comment: None others were found in the search I did on your specifications and they didn't come in under $400.